# passport local mongoose req.user undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm currently encountering the following problem during implementation of passport js with the passport local mongoose plugin. Account creation and logging in is working correctly. However, after I have logged in passport never identifies me as a user that is logged in.

I have used the following pieces of code:

In my user model:

```
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
```

In app.js (this order of inclusion is correct?):

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

In my routes:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
  res.json({ loggedIn: true });
});
```

which returns true, but the following keeps returning false (after logging in):

```
req.isAuthenticated()
```

Can anyone enlighten me what the cause may be?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to implement a quick way to make sure your users are authenticated before they visit parts of your application? If so, I would suggest a simple way where you create an express.js middleware that will check if user is logged in, and if not - will redirect to the `/login` page.

Comment: `res.json({ loggedIn: true }); ` will always return true.  Does `res.json({loggedIn: req.isAuthenticated()})` return true?

Comment: res.json({ loggedIn: true });

does not always return true. passport.authenticate('local') is middleware that does not call next() when the authentication failed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try an Express middelware, as was suggested in the comments.

For example:

```
 function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    } else {
        // redirect users to login page
    }
 }

 app.get('/anypage', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    // some reoute logic
 })
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. req.isAuthenticated() always returns false even tho I succesfully logged in before. I have the feeling that its a session/cookies problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, your order is fine. The most important part of the order is to have `passport.initialize()` and `passport.session()` come after your `express-session` configuration.

As for the issue with the initial authentication working, but subsequent requests showing an unauthenticated user, the issue could very well be because of cookies. I have run into a similar issue before, and the problem was in the way the HTTP requests were being made from the client.

If you are using the ES6 `fetch` API, then you will want to make sure to pass in an key `credentials` to the options object with a value of `"include"`.

For example:

```
fetch('/restricted', {
  method: 'get',
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

The `fetch` API will not send credentials in cookies unless you specify it to. Hope this helps.

Additional resources: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch